# Applying Schauder fixed point theorem to a map (explanation needed)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $F:L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ be continuous map. Let $D$ be a function space.

> Since $F(L^2(\Omega)) \subset D$, and $D \subset L^2(\Omega)$ is a compact embedding, $F$ is a compact operator from $L^2(\Omega)$ into itself. So Schauder's fixed point theorem applies and $F$ has a fixed point.

(The source also mentions that $|F(w)|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq R$ for all $w$, but I don't know whether this is for all $w \in D$ or $w \in L^2(\Omega).$)

Can someone explain to me how this works when looking at the classical statement of the Schauder fixed point theorem? They seem to use $L^2(\Omega)$ as the closed convex subset.. but shouldn't there be a bigger space involved too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is compact, then so is the closure of its convex closure $K=\overline{\mathrm{co}(D)}$.

Hence, you have a compact map $F: K\to D\subset K$, which according to Schauder FPT possesses a fixed point, as no $K$ is compact and convex.

Comment: So $K=L^2(\Omega)$ here? ($D = \{ u \in L^2(0,T;V) : u_t \in L^2(0,T;V^*)\}$ for reference)

Comment: @weasd: $K$ is compact (and thus bounded) and convex subset of $L^2(\Omega)$. The space $L^2(\Omega)$ is not compact.

Comment: OK thanks. I think the bound $|F(w)| \leq R$ is not used, is that right?